# Table cell as the delegate of the text field inside it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I unfortunately still have not seen the light when it comes to organising my iphone app nicely into controllers and views. Let me illustrate with an example:

I am working on a sign up page which consists of a table view with a list of custom table cells. Some of these cells have a text field inside them and when the user touches one of those a keyboard slides up from the bottom. The keyboard has a return key in its lower right corner and when the user hits this key I would like the keyboard to slide down again.

Now, where do I put the

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

? Currently I have made my custom table cell conform to the text field delegate protocol and have put the method in there, but it does seem a bit wrong to have stuff like that inside a view class? On the other hand I do not find it appropriate in the table view controller either.

Answer (score 4):

you can set your table view controller as the text field's delegate...
just remove the code in the custom cell where you set it as the delegate and instead set the delegate in the table view controller's cellForRowAtIndexPath method where you actually create and return the cell..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {              
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";


    MyCustomCell *myCell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (myCell == nil)
    {

        myCell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        myCell.myTextField.delegate = self;
    }

    //other cell specific code goes here

    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: But to me that does not separate the code very nicely? Or am I getting things all wrong here? :/

Comment: but this code belongs in the contrller.. any specific reason why you aren't comfortable with having it in there?

Comment: Maybe he prefer to have the textfield itself control the delegate? How would you suggest the textfield to take responsibility of the delelgate controls if he subclasses the UITextfield?